# Points in linear general position in a section of a curve in $\mathbb P^{n}(\mathbb C)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, cohen-macaulay

Given a natural number $p\in \mathbb N \setminus{0}$,  let $X\subseteq\mathbb P^{g+p+1}(\mathbb C)$ be a curve of genus $p$ and degree $2g+p+1$, and $Y\subseteq \mathbb P^{g+p}$ a general hyperplane section of $X$. Then $Y$ consists in a set of $2g+p+1$ points in linear general position: why are these points in linear general position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the result below, known as *General Position Theorem*.

> **General Position Theorem.** Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^r$, $r>2$, be an irreducible, non-degenerate, possibly singular curve of degree $d$. Then a general hyperplane meets $C$ in $d$ points any $r$ of which are linearly independent.

For a proof you can see Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths, Harris: *Geometry of Algebraic Curves I*, p. 109 (Chapter III).